# Best practice to use $? in bash?

Tags: shell, bash, error-handling

When I read this [answer about $?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7704/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-shell-script/7714#7714) another question comes to mind.

Is there any best practice for how to use $? in bash?

---

Let's have a example:

We have a linear script and I we would like to know that all the command was executed ok.
Do you think it is ok to call a small function (let's call it "did_it_work"), 
to check the error code and break if it's not.

```
#!/bin/bash 

function did_it_work {
    code=$1
    if [ "$code" -ne "0" ]
    then
        echo "Error failure: code $code "
        exit 1
    fi
}

dir=some/path

mkdir -p $dir
did_it_work $? 

cd $dir
did_it_work $? 

run_some_command
did_it_work $?
```

This approach of course means that I have to manually solve the problem if there is any and rerun the script.

Do you think this is a good idea or is there some other best practice to do this?

/Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One common way is:

```
die() {
    IFS=' ' # make sure "$*" is joined with spaces

    # output the arguments if any on stderr:
    [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$*" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

then you use it like this:

```
mkdir -p some/path || die "mkdir failed with status $?"
```

Or if you want it to include the exit status, you could change it to:

```
die() {
    last_exit_status=$?
    IFS=' '
    printf '%s\n' "FATAL ERROR: $* (status $last_exit_status)" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

and then using it is a bit easier:

```
mkdir -p some/path || die "mkdir failed"
```

When it fails, `mkdir` will likely already have issued an error message, so that second one may be seen as redundant, and you could just do:

```
mkdir -p some/path || exit   # with the same (failing) exit status as mkdir's
mkdir -p some/path || exit 1 # with exit status 1 always
```

(or use the first variant of `die` above without argument)

Just in case you haven't seen `command1 || command2` before, it runs `command1`, and if `command1` fails, it runs `command2`.

So you can read it like "make the directory or die".

Your example would look like:

```
mkdir -p some/path || die "mkdir failed"
cd some/path || die "cd failed"
some_command || die "some_command failed"
```

Or you can align the `dies` further on the right so that the main code is more obvious.

```
mkdir -p some/path         || die "mkdir failed"
cd some/path               || die "cd failed"
some_command               || die "some_command failed"
```

Or on the following line when the command lines are long:

```
mkdir -p some/path ||
  die "mkdir failed"

cd some/path ||
  die "cd failed"

some_command ||
  die "some_command failed"
```

---

Also, if you are going to use the name `some/path` multiple times, store it in a variable so you don't have to keep typing it, and can easily change it if you need to. And when passing variable arguments to commands, make sure to use the `--` option delimiter so that the argument is not taken as an option if it starts with `-`.

```
dir=some/path
mkdir -p -- "$dir"         || die "Cannot make $dir"
cd -P -- "$dir"            || die "Cannot cd to $dir"
some_command               || die "Cannot run some_command"
```

Answer (score 9):

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function try {
    "$@"
    code=$?
    if [ $code -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "$1 did not work: exit status $code"
        exit 1
    fi
}

try mkdir -p some/path
try cd some/path
try run_some_command
```

If you don't actually need to log the error code, but just whether the command succeeded or not, you can shorten `try()` further like so:

```
function try {
    if ! "$@"
    then
        echo "$1 did not work"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: You can also use the code in this format. <pre>function try {

Comment: If you use this functionality inline and don't want to return from the true side you can replace `return $?` with the `:` builtin.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to `exit` on an error and are using Bash, then you should also consider `set -e`.  From `help set`:

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

This of course doesn't give you the flexibility of a did_it_work() function, but it is an easy way to make sure your bash script stops on an error without adding lots of calls to your new function.

Comment: `set -e` is useful. There are some commands that return non-zero under normal circumstances (for instance, `diff`). When I'm using set -e in a script where I'm expecting a nonzero return, I do `command || true`.

Comment: Furthermore, even if you use `set -e`, you can set an “exception handler” to catch all errors with `trap did_it_work EXIT`.

Comment: This is part of POSIX, not a bash specific feature. Use it but be aware of some pitfalls http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff I prefer to do `command && true`. Like that the return value is *not* changed.

Comment: @kmkaplan Your last comment doesn't make any sense to me. The purpose of `command || true` is to prevent `set -e` from exiting the script if `command` returns a non-zero exit code. It changes the exit code because we need to. The only thing `command && true` does is run `true` (return a zero exit code) if `command succeeded (returned a zero exit code) - it's a complete no-op.

Comment: @tripleee No. `command && true` also prevents `set -e` from exiting the script if `command` returns a non-zero exit code. But it (mostly) does *not* change the exit code whereas `command || true` does.

Comment: @kmkaplan Wow, TIL! Thanks for taking the time to explain this.