# Bash: run command2 if command1 fails

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

I want to do something like this:

```
if cmd1 && cmd2
echo success
else
echo epic fail
fi
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You're just missing the "then" keyword before the "echo success" command.

Comment: Hmmm; your pseudocode seems to ask a different question than the one in your title.....

Comment: Good resource for some shell scripting exit conditions http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/shell_script_mistakes.html

Answer (score 134, accepted):

These should do what you need:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && echo success || echo epic fail
```

or

```
if cmd1 && cmd2; then
    echo success
else
    echo epic fail
fi
```

Comment: This works, but I'm confused why `||` doesn't look at the output of the first `echo` command.

Comment: @mlissner, the if else expects to exit codes, 0 if the command where launched and 1 if where errors. Do not read at the output. `Just try whoami && whoami && echo success || echo epic fail` and now `whoami && whoareyou && echo success || echo epic fail`. I cant figure out what you mean by "doesn't look at the output of the first echo command"

Comment: @mlissner I think I got your question, but the answer is that echo command won't fail ever. That is, its return will be 0, i.e. truthy. So the condition that really matters is just `cmd1 && cmd2`

Comment: `printf "$(( 1/0 ))" || echo "failed"` does not work. However, putting `printf "$(( 1/0 ))"` in step_1.sh, then running `./step_1.sh || echo "failed"` behaves as expected.

Answer (score 116):

The pseudo-code in the question does not correspond to the title of the question.

If anybody needs to actually know how to run command 2 if command 1 fails, this is a simple explanation:

- `cmd1 || cmd2`: This will run `cmd1`, and in case of failure it will run `cmd2`
- `cmd1 && cmd2`: This will run `cmd1`, and in case of success it will run `cmd2`
- `cmd1 ; cmd2`: This will run `cmd1`, and then it will run `cmd2`, independent of the failure or success of running `cmd1`.

---

For completeness, in your example you missed the `then` keyword. The code you tried to show would be written as

`if cmd1 && cmd2; then echo success; else echo epic fail; fi`

Which is equivalent to

`((cmd1 && cmd2) && echo success) || echo epic fail`

And parenthesis are optional due to [left-associativity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators).

Note that in these codes, `cmd2` will be run only in case of success of running `cmd1`, otherwise it echo fail directly.

Answer (score 32):

Petr Uzel is spot on but you can also play with the magic $?.

$? holds the exit code from the last command executed, 
and if you use this you can write your scripts quite flexible.

This questions touches this topic a little bit, [Best practice to use $? in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/best-practice-to-use-in-bash) .

```
cmd1 
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "Fail"
fi
```

Then you also can react to different exit codes and do different things if you like.