# Precedence of the shell logical operators &&, ||

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to understand how the logical operator precedence works in bash. For example, I would have expected, that the following command does not echo anything.

```
true || echo aaa && echo bbb
```

However, contrary to my expectation, `bbb` gets printed.

Can somebody please explain, how can I make sense of compounded `&&` and `||` operators in bash?

Comment: This has confused me a lot in trying to write shell script pipelines with different logic based on some test (e.g. exiting if a file doesn't exist vs continuing the pipeline).

Answer (score 210, accepted):

In many computer languages, operators with the same precedence are [left-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). That is, in the absence of grouping structures, leftmost operations are executed first. Bash is [no exception](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) to this rule.

This is important because in Bash and other shells `&&` and `||` have the same precedence. This is different from most other programming languages which usually give `&&` a higher precedence than `||`.

So what happens in your example is that the leftmost operation (`||`) is carried out first:

```
true || echo aaa
```

Since `true` is obviously true, the `||` operator short-circuits and the whole statement is considered true without the need to evaluate `echo aaa` as you would expect. Now it remains to do the rightmost operation:

```
(...) && echo bbb
```

Since the first operation evaluated to true (i.e. had a 0 exit status), it's as if you're executing

```
true && echo bbb
```

so the `&&` will not short-circuit, which is why you see `bbb` echoed.

You would get the same behavior with

```
false && echo aaa || echo bbb
```

**Notes based on the comments**

- You should note that the left-associativity rule is *only* followed when both operators have *the same* precedence. This is not the case when you use these operators in conjunction with keywords such as `[[...]]` or `((...))` or use the `-o` and `-a` operators as arguments to the `test` or `[` commands. In such cases, AND (`&&` or `-a`) takes precedence over OR (`||` or `-o`). Thanks to Stephane Chazelas' comment for clarifying this point.
- It seems that [in C](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) and C-like languages `&&` has higher precedence than `||` which is probably why you expected your original construct to behave like

  ```
  true || (echo aaa && echo bbb).
  ```

This is not the case with Bash, however, in which both operators have the same precedence, which is why Bash parses your expression using the left-associativity rule. Thanks to Kevin's comment for bringing this up.

- There might also be cases where *all 3* expressions are evaluated. If the first command returns a non-zero exit status, the `||` won't short circuit and goes on to execute the second command. If the second command returns with a zero exit status, then the `&&` won't short-circuit as well and the third command will be executed. Thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' comment for bringing this up.

Comment: A wee note to add a little more confusion: while the `&&` and `||` shell operators as in `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` have same precedence, the `&&` in `((...))` and `[[...]]` has precedence over `||` (`((a || b && c))` is `((a || (b && c)))`). Same goes for `-a`/`-o` in `test`/`[` and `find` and `&`/`|` in `expr`.

Comment: In c-like languages, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the OP's expected behavior would happen. Unwary users used to such languages may not realize that in bash they have the same precedence, so it may be worth pointing out more explicitly that they do have the same precedence in bash.

Comment: Also note that there are situations where *all three* commands can be run, i.e. if the middle command can return either true *or* false.

Comment: @Kevin Please check edited answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Please check edited answer.

Comment: Today, for me, the top Google hit for "bash operator precedence" is http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html... which claims that && has a higher precedence than ||.  Yet @JosephR. is clearly right de facto and de jure too.  Dash behaves the same and searching for "precedence" in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html, I see it's a POSIX requirement, so we can depend on it.  All I found for bug reporting was the author's email address, which has surely been spammed to death in the last six years.  I'll try anyway...

Comment: "Thank you for your comments, but unfortunately I am no longer updating or maintaining the ABS Guide."

Comment: @MartinDorey I read that page the same way as you, but having read the above answer, I am now interpreting the blank rows as "group separators" so that adjacent (non-blank) rows are of equal precedence.

Comment: What about single ampresand. Does it evaluate to true, or it is just ignored?

Comment: Yea the ABS guide appears high in Google results even in 2022 so this is very confusing to people unaware of the difference between Bash and C-like languages.

Comment: Note that if you want to only specify precendence without launching subshells, you have to use syntax such as `false || { echo aaa && echo bbb; }`. Note that the space after `{` is not optional and the semicolon is required before `}`. Parenthesis (`(` and `)`) cause commands to be evaluated in subshell which may or may not be what you want but you shouldn't assume that parenthesis can be used simply to declare precendence.

Comment: the operator table on that tldp.org page seems to contain operators like `++` and `<` which are supported within arithmetic contexts (`$((...))` and `((..))` plus a couple others), as well as operators like `-a` and `-f` supported in `[[...]]`, so it's not exactly clear what it's trying to show there. But in both of those contexts, `&&` does have higher precedence than `||`, so it's not entirely wrong.

Answer (score 113):

If you want multiple things to depend on your condition, group them:

```
true || { echo aaa && echo bbb; }
```

That prints nothing, while

```
true && { echo aaa && echo bbb; }
```

prints both strings.

---

The reason this happens is a lot more simple than Joseph is making out. Remember what Bash does with `||` and `&&`. It's all about the previous command's return status. A literal way of looking at your raw command is:

```
( true || echo aaa ) && echo bbb
```

The first command (`true || echo aaa`) is exiting with `0`.

```
$ true || echo aaa; echo $?
0
$ true && echo aaa; echo $?
aaa
0

$ false && echo aaa; echo $?
1
$ false || echo aaa; echo $?
aaa
0
```

Comment: +1 For achieving the OP's intended outcome. Note that the parentheses you placed in `(true || echo aaa) && echo bbb` is exactly what I'm making out.

Comment: Note the semi-column `;` at the very end. Without this, it will not work!

Comment: I was running into trouble with this because I was missing the trailing semi-colon after the last command (e.g. `echo bbb;` in the first examples). Once I figured out I was missing that, this answer was exactly what I was looking for. +1 for helping me figure out how to accomplish what I wanted!

Comment: Worth reading for anyone confused by `(...)` and `{...}` notation: [command grouping manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

Comment: Joseph's answer was simple, but didn't offer the bracket syntax.  Yours does, but could be simpler if you make it clear whether `{}` and `()` are both allowed and equivalent.

Comment: This is the key: `( true || echo aaa ) && echo bbb`, which explains how the OS interprets the raw command.

Answer (score 23):

The `&&` and `||` operators are ***not*** exact inline replacements for if-then-else. Though if used carefully, they can accomplish much the same thing.

A single test is straightforward and unambiguous...

```
[[ A == A ]]  && echo TRUE                          # TRUE
[[ A == B ]]  && echo TRUE                          # 
[[ A == A ]]  || echo FALSE                         # 
[[ A == B ]]  || echo FALSE                         # FALSE
```

However, attempting to add multiple tests may yield unexpected results...

```
[[ A == A ]]  && echo TRUE   || echo FALSE          # TRUE  (as expected)
[[ A == B ]]  && echo TRUE   || echo FALSE          # FALSE (as expected)
[[ A == A ]]  || echo FALSE  && echo TRUE           # TRUE  (as expected)
[[ A == B ]]  || echo FALSE  && echo TRUE           # FALSE TRUE   (huh?)
```

Why are both FALSE *and* TRUE echoed?

What's happening here is that we've not realized that `&&` and `||` are overloaded operators that act differently inside conditional test brackets `[[ ]]` than they do in the AND and OR (conditional execution) list we have here.

From the bash manpage (edited)...

> Lists
>
> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
>   operators ;, &, &&, or ││, and optionally terminated by one of ;, &,
>   or . Of these list operators, && and ││ have equal
>   precedence, followed by ; and &, which have equal precedence.
>
> A sequence of one or more newlines may appear in a list instead of a
>   semicolon to delimit commands.
>
> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.
>   Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits
>   for each command to terminate in turn. The return status is the exit
>   status of the last command executed.
>
> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by
>   the && and ││ control operators, respectively. AND and OR lists are
>   executed with left associativity.
>
> An AND list has the form ...
>       `command1 && command2`
>   Command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form ...
>       `command1 ││ command2`
>   Command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.
>
> The return status of AND and OR lists
>   is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.

Returning to our last example...

```
[[ A == B ]]  || echo FALSE  && echo TRUE

[[ A == B ]]  is false

     ||       Does NOT mean OR! It means...
              'execute next command if last command return code(rc) was false'

 echo FALSE   The 'echo' command rc is always true
              (i.e. it successfully echoed the word "FALSE")

     &&       Execute next command if last command rc was true

 echo TRUE    Since the 'echo FALSE' rc was true, then echo "TRUE"
```

Okay. If that's correct, then why does the next to last example echo anything at all?

```
[[ A == A ]]  || echo FALSE  && echo TRUE


[[ A == A ]]  is true

     ||       execute next command if last command rc was false.

 echo FALSE   Since last rc was true, shouldn't it have stopped before this?
                Nope. Instead, it skips the 'echo FALSE', does not even try to
                execute it, and continues looking for a `&&` clause.

     &&       ... which it finds here

 echo TRUE    ... so, since `[[ A == A ]]` is true, then it echos "TRUE"
```

The risk of logic errors when using more than one `&&` or `||` in a command list is quite high.

**Recommendations**

A single `&&` or `||` in a command list works as expected so is pretty safe. If it's a situation where you don't need an else clause, something like the following can be clearer to follow (the curly braces are required to group the last 2 commands) ...

```
[[ $1 == --help ]]  && { echo "$HELP"; exit; }
```

Multiple `&&` and `||` operators, where each command except for the last is a test (i.e. inside brackets `[[ ]]`), are usually also safe as all but the last operator behave as expected. The last operator acts more like a `then` or `else` clause.

Comment: I like your (implicit) recommendation to stick to one operator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a neat example:

```
% true || true && false;echo $?
1
% true || (true && false);echo $?
0
```

`true` is a command that does nothing and has the exit status 0 meaning "true".

The content of the parentheses runs in a subshell.  `echo $?` displays the exit status of the last command.

Moreover, the question is self-contradictory: `||` and `&&` in the context of the question are not logical operators but command compositors. (Roughly, they belong to modal not boolean logic.)

If you are indeed interested in logical operators `&&` and `||` on strings, occuring inside test `[[...]]`, [`&&` precedes `||`](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html) so that for example

```
%  [[ 0 || 0 && '' ]];echo $? 
0
%  [[ (0 || 0) && '' ]];echo $?
1
```

A string is true if and only if it is not empty.

Abstractly of exit status:

```
% if [[ 0 || 0 && '' ]];then echo oui;else echo non;fi
oui
% if [[ (0 || 0) && '' ]];then echo oui;else echo non;fi
non
```

All this applies to `zsh` or `bash`.

Answer (score -1):

I also got confused by this but here's how I think about the way Bash reads your statement (as it reads the symbols left to right):

1. Found symbol `true`. This will need to be evaluated once the end of the command is reached. At this point, don't know if it has any arguments. Store command in execution buffer.
2. Found symbol `||`. Previous command is now complete, so evaluate it. Command (buffer) being executed: `true`. Result of evaluation: 0 (i.e. success). Store result 0 in "last evaluation" register. Now consider symbol `||` itself. This depends on the result of the last evaluation being non-zero. Checked "last evaluation" register and found 0. Since 0 is not non-zero, the following command does not need to be evaluated.
3. Found symbol `echo`. Can ignore this symbol, because the following command did not need to be evaluated.
4. Found symbol `aaa`. This is an argument to command `echo` (3), but since `echo` (3) did not need to be evaluated, it can be ignored.
5. Found symbol `&&`. This depends on the result of the last evaluation being zero. Checked "last evaluation" register and found 0. Since 0 is zero, the following command does need to be evaluated.
6. Found symbol `echo`. This command needs to be evaluated once the end of the command is reached, because the following command did need to be evaluated. Store command in execution buffer.
7. Found symbol `bbb`. This is an argument to command `echo` (6). Since `echo` did need to be evaluated, add `bbb` to execution buffer.
8. Reached end of line. Previous command is now complete and did need to be evaluated. Command (buffer) being executed: `echo bbb`. Result of evaluation: 0 (i.e. success). Store result 0 in "last evaluation" register.

And of course, the last step causes `bbb` to be echoed to the console.