# [: missing `]' error in shell, already have spaces before and after the code in []

Tags: shell

code:

```
if [ $mintemp -ge 15 && $maxtemp -le 28 ]; then echo "nice day"; fi
```

I already have spaces between [ and $Mintemp , 28 and ]

but the error still happend

Comment: Related: [Multiple logical operators, ((A || B) && C), and “syntax error near unexpected token”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290146/multiple-logical-operators-a-b-c-and-syntax-error-near-unexpected-t)

Comment: Are you using /bin/bash or /bin/sh? If you're using bash specifically, use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` and then `&&` is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` is not a `[]` argument (since `[` is actually a program), it is Bash's operator for running second command if the first one succeeds. So for bash your script looks like:

```
if ([ $mintemp -ge 15) && ($maxtemp -le 28 ]; then echo "nice day"; fi)
```

Which is invalid. You can however do it like:

```
if [ $mintemp -ge 15 ] && [ $maxtemp -le 28 ]; then echo "nice day"; fi
```

Comment: thanks, but another error happends:  ` [: too many arguments`