# Missing operator issue

Tags: ksh

I was trying to do an OR logic in If condition

```
condition 1 => warning ="" and err_code !=1
OR
condition 2 => threshold =1 and threshold_load_ind=Y and err_code!=1
```

This is throwing an operator level issue . What is missing in the if code

```
if [  "$warn" != ""  &&  "$err_ind" != 1  ] || [  $thres_err_ind == 1   &&  $thres_load_ind == "Y"  &&  $err_ind != 1  ];then
```

error code at line 860

```
[860]: [: ']' missing
[860]: [: ']' missing
```

Comment: @zevzek  i changed to  if [ [ "$warn" != "" ]  &&  [ "$err_ind" != 1  ]] || [ [ $thres_err_ind == 1 ]  && [ $thres_load_ind == "Y" ] && [ $err_ind != 1 ] ]     but still has the unknown operator issue

Answer (score 4):

`[` is regular command (with a funny name), *not* part of the shell syntax. Just to make it look confusingly like a syntax element, it expects to see `]` as its last argument. But `&&` and `||` are part of the shell syntax and they separate commands. So your if-statement has five commands, marked below:

```
if [ "$warn" != ""  && "$err_ind" != 1  ] ||
   1^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    2^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   [ $thres_err_ind == 1 && $thres_load_ind == "Y" && $err_ind != 1 ];
   3^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    4^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    5^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first one runs `[` with the three arguments containing the contents of `$warn`, `!=`, and an empty string. There's no `]`, so the `[` command complains. Since it fails, the following command after `&&` doesn't run, but the one after `||` does, and complains for the similar reason. (If the others would run, they'd probably give you "command not found" errors, since the variables are in command position, and if e.g. `err_ind` contained `0`, the shell would try to run the command `0`.)

Also, the shell's `&&` and `||` operators have *equal* precedence, so `a && bb || c && d` acts like `( (a && bb) || c) && d`, which is probably not what you want.

So, you need to both add the closing `]` before the `&&`/`||`, and to group the commands manually:

```
if { [ ... ] && [ ... ]; } ||
   { [ ... ] && [ ... ] && [ ... ]; }; then ...
```

or with parentheses, which don't require the pesky `;` at the end, but launch subshells, which is a slight performance loss:

```
if ( [ ... ] && [ ... ] ) ||
   ( [ ... ] && [ ... ] && [ ... ] ); then ...
```

Or switch to using the `[[` test (in Bash/ksh/zsh), which *is* shell syntax and works with different rules and supports `&&`/`||`.

See:

- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373) and
- [Precedence of the shell logical operators &&, ||](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88850/170373)

Comment: if  { [ "$warn" != "" ]   && [  "$err_ind" != 1  ] } || { [ $thres_err_ind == 1 ]  && [  $thres_load_ind == "Y" ]  && [  $err_ind != 1 ] }; then                .............................. i tried this code but now the error is "then " unexpected .Any thoughts on this